# Why can't I bomb Rome?

Tags: civilization-5

As you can see from the image below, I have a great war bomber with Rome in range. However, when I click the attack button and click on Rome (I can see my damage and Rome's damage), nothing happens. The attack is not carried out. Am I missing something here?

[image: Cannot attack Rome]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at your screen capture, Rome is covered by shroud (not in view of any other units). From personal experience, air units cannot attack cities which are not in the view of another unit (shrouded). This is why I always buy a ton of submarines. They have a huge visibility range and aren't easily detectable. You can just send one to go sit a little ways away from the city so it's in view, then use your air units as much as you want.

As far as I know, only nuclear/atomic weapons can be launched to areas which are covered by shroud.

Comment: For anyone no aware, shroud can also be called *"fog of war"*.

Comment: Isn't Fog of war the actual clouded tiles? Rather than the dark tiles.

Comment: (cc @Braiam) I thought shroud was the black stuff that you've *never* seen (animuson's "unexplored territory"), and fog of war is the grey stuff you can't see *right now*.

Comment: @michaelb958 The vagueness of their definitions makes them both kind of synonymous to each other, which makes things confusing in games that have two levels of it. That's why I always include other descriptions to indicate exactly what I mean, in this case something that is out of view. -- Then there are the games which really throw you off and call it shroud of war.

Comment: You can also send a spy to that city to grant you vision of it and the directly surrounding tiles.